# That’s the Prince of Wales addressing the Queen

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “If we were an ordinary family and social services came to visit, they’d have thrown us into care and you into jail!” ***That***’s ***the Prince of Wales addressing the Queen***, as played by Dominic West and Imelda Staunton.

[Source](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/tv/0/crown-netflix-season-5-review-royal-dirty-laundry-re-aired-viewing/)

---

I'm not sure what "***That***" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**That**" refers to the previous quote. It means, "**The words I have just quoted** were (said by) the Prince of Wales, who said this while addressing the Queen..."

Comment: I wonder if "***the Prince of Wales addressing the Queen***" means "***the Prince of Wales*** who was ***addressing the Queen***".

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss I have clarified my answer. That help?